# Why does checking for updates take so long and use so much data?

Tags: installation, upgrade, apt

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and checked for updates - it took about 15mB (very rough estimate) and 15min (on a uncapped ADSL line approx 30kB/s) just to see that I should download 7mB of updates. This is not something new, same thing when I add a PPA to install a tiny program - I have to wait 15-20 min just to install it.

And I have an uncapped Internet connection, what about users that doesn't have uncapped Internet? Why is it that everything else on Ubuntu is moving forward, this critical part is not progressing? The new Software Centre is great, but it is driving me insane that it is taking so long. Also the updating cache messages are misleading - it says downloading 2 of 3 files, then 4 of 6 files, eventually 80 of 113 files - it feels like my computer is lying to me, and I have no idea how long it is going to take to check for the updates!!!

Comment: How many ppa's have you added?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score -2):

FC, as technology continuosly progresses (hardware and software features) it makes it so much more complex to integrate everything. And then the rest of the *shabang* that makes it a rich and interactive experience. This obviously means more frequent tweaks and tunes and patching and innovating.

And when your updates are coming from all over the place(custom repos), we can understand why Ubuntu's newer releases require so much more throughput from the other side.

Having said that, I have to agree with you. I am limited to 10GB per month and the bandwidth used by the update system adds up significantly.

Areas of the world where household consumers don't have easy access to true broadband (eg. RSA) makes it more difficult to integrate the whole Ubuntu experience effeciently.

Time & Cost used to be main advantages of Ubuntu, for me.

**--Discussion aside, i have a suggestion--**

It's still very early for the latest release, but...

Have a look at [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_katya_whatsnew.php). Scroll down and have a look at [their development team's update manager](http://www.linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/katya/mintupdate.png). I find it revolutionary. And my system tends to be MUCH more stable.

It's a linux distrobution directly based on fabulous Ubuntu :D

Give it a try when the 11.10 based version releases.